# neo4j cypher collection of paths to collection of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have collection of paths P and want my query to return only a simple collection of nodes (a node per row) containing all the nodes from every path. Seems like a trivial task but after this error from the DB I gave up trying :D .

thanks

[image: Output from web console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh, so it really was trivial after all...

```
... UNWIND nodes(p) as aaa RETURN DISTINCT aaa
```